# Set or edit field values of table rows that have a matching other value in Python 3 and sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.9

Is there a way in sqlite3 in Python 3 to edit/set the `description` of the last two rows of the table `animals` here, because they have a matching date?

| id | date | animal | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-04-01 | bird | domestic canary |
| 1 | 2022-04-06 | cat | NULL |
| 2 | 2022-04-06 | dog | NULL |

When I use the following command, nothing really happens:

`UPDATE animals SET description='unknown' WHERE description IS NULL AND date=2022-04-06`

I guess it finds the 2 rows matching the date, but doesn't know which one to edit.

Is there a simple way to set the `description` for both without having to bring the `id`, as secondary reference column, into play? `id` is the primary keyed column.

Thanks.

Comment: The date should be enclosed inside single quotes `AND date='2022-04-01'`, but the last 2 rows have date `'2022-04-06'` and not `'2022-04-01'`

Comment: @forpas, thanks putting single quotes solved the issue!